# Разметка программно

Tags: android

Помогите программно сделать разметку ,как на фото снизу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 LinearLayout ALL = new LinearLayout(this);
    ALL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams ALLParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ALL.setLayoutParams(ALLParams);
    LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams LLParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LL.setWeightSum(6f);
    LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
    FrameLayout ladderFL = new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ladderFLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER);
    ladderFL.setLayoutParams(ladderFLParams);
    ladderFL.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.asad));
    LinearLayout LL1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LL1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams LLParams1 = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LL1.setWeightSum(6f);
    LL1.setLayoutParams(LLParams1);
    ladderFL.addView(ladder);
    LL.addView(ladderFL);
    LL1.addView(dummyView);
    LL1.addView(closeB);
    ALL.addView(LL1);
    ALL.addView(LL);
    RelativeLayout rl=((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative));
    rl.addView(ALL);
```

Написал но все не так как нужно,много кода ,хотя знаю что можно вложится в пару строк,вообщем в первые пробую программно создать разметку.

Comment: Сделайте сначала нужную разметку в xml, чтобы понять какие параметры нужно установить. А уже потом просто перенесита всё это в код. Но скажу сразу, что без дополнительной вью по центру корневого релейтива, так отцентровать линеры не получится.

Comment: @eugeneek если это делать сначала в xml, то двойная работа получается.

Comment: @Suvitruf я имел ввиду в учебных целях. Понятно, что двойная работа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    LinearLayout parentLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
    parentLinear.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 160, Gravity.BOTTOM));
    parentLinear.setWeightSum(1f);
    parentLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutLeft = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayoutLeft.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f));
    linearLayoutLeft.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutRight = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayoutRight.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f));
    linearLayoutRight.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutRight.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    parentLinear.addView(linearLayoutLeft);
    parentLinear.addView(linearLayoutRight);
    frameLayout.addView(parentLinear);

    setContentView(frameLayout);
}
```

не забывайте что 160, это высота в пикселях, желательно прогонять через утилитарный класс, где учитывается плотность экрана. Типо.

```
AppUtils.dp(160)
```

Динамическая верстка акутальная тема, в одном из маленьких проектов использовали Anvil, что типо react верстки, мб пригодится.
https://github.com/zserge/anvil